Issue with MICE package and generation of logistic regression
I am using a publicly available dataset (National Health Interview Survey). I am studying heart disease as the outcome variable and examining the impact of several clinicodemographic factors on prevalence and odds of heart disease.
I did multiple imputation with the MICE package in R (v 4.4.0) and had no issues with multiple imputation. After the multiple imputation, I extracted the first imputed complete dataset and used the head function to look at the first few rows to double check that, in fact, the multiple imputation procedure had worked. Everything was fine. Afterwards, I proceeded to try to complete a logistic regression analysis using the multiply imputed data. Please refer to the code below. In my first step, I turned the datasets into long format. Second, I converted I back to MIDS type data since MICE can work with this type of data. Third, I generate the logistic regression. However, whenever I try to do the logistic regression, I obtain an error that states: "Error in as.data.frame.default(merge8imp_long_mids) : cannot coerce class '"mids"' to a data.frame" I tried removing the pool() function in the multivariate model, but that did not help. I even tried to use the merge8_imp_long (the complete imputed dataset in long format), but that required me to specify weights = NULL and it never loaded (I waited for over half an hour and the logistic regression procedure never completed).
Here are details about the merge_8imp_long_mids:
enter image description here
merge8imp_long <- mice::complete(imp2, action="long", include = TRUE)

merge8imp_long_mids <-as.mids(merge8imp_long)


model_fitimp <- pool(with(merge8imp_long_mids,
                                glm(HeartDisease_Binary2 ~ AgeCat + Sex2 + RaceEthnicity + SexualOrientation + Education + IncomePovertyRatio + BMICategory, HealthInsurance2, 
                                    data = merge8imp_long_mids,
                                    family = "binomial",
                                    weights = NULL)))

I would greatly appreciate any help with troubleshooting this. I am very frustrated because I have finally reached the last step of multiple imputation only to have it not work for the logistic regression, which is the output data that I need for this procedure. I would really appreciate any help or insight. Thanks so much! :)

Can you make this into a small, reproducible example? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example if you need any tips on how to go about it.

As long as we cannot reproduce the problem (see the other comment), we can only suggest other things to try. For instance, have you tried using the pool_glm function from the miceafter package? I am not sure whether mice::pool is even expected to work with a glm. Another approach may program the fitting to each imputation yourself and pool the statistic of interest via mice::pool.scalar. This answer is about a similar case.
